# before_action and nested attributes for models

Tags: ruby

The question is really simple.
Please, take a look at my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170812094528) do

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "parent_id"
  end

  create_table "parents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "item_id"
  end

end
```

This is how models looks like:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :item

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item
  before_create :set_something 

  def set_something
    self.item.build
  end
end
```

and

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

The question: When creating a Parent, why does it raise the following error?

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

How should I set this up so that I can add and item record at the same time as creating a parent?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
def set_something
    build_item
end
```

The model Parent `has_one :item`. In Rails, the `has_one` association adds a helper method `build_association(attributes = {})` to the owner class, and not `association.build(attributes = {})`. This is the reason that you are getting the error `undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass`.

Please see the [has_one documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one) for more details on has_one association.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much for help! In the "Items" table new record is added with a proper "user_id" value. Another question is: in the "Parents" table, my new record has item_id = nill value. I just wonder if I even need this item_id column in "parents" table. What do you think? Is there any easy way to resolve this issue?

Comment: why do you need item_id in parents table
you can get parents object by using item object
like @Item.parent